# Letting modules access a Local in the parent script

Tags: lua, scoping

#### Update:

Some further reading ([local variable cannot be seen in a closure across the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324376/local-variable-cannot-be-seen-in-a-closure-across-the-file)) gave me an "aha!" moment as to exactly why my code didn't work.

In Lua, *local x* is visible to anything within the same scope - things in the same function, if/then structures, for loops, other functions called from that function, etc, but **not** other modules, even if they're called from within the local's scope. I haven't found a better explanation than "because reasons", but simply knowing that modules are an exception to the "normal" scope behavior at least puts my mind at ease.

#### Original post:

(Terribly sorry if there's an answer for this out there; I've been Googling for a couple of hours and come up short.)

I've written a GUI library for my preferred audio software (Reaper). There's a strong potential for scripts to be running during recording/playback, so performance is a big issue, and I'm trying to keep everything Local where possible. Easy enough, in general, but I'm having a bit of trouble when it comes to using the GUI library + element classes in a script.

Main GUI module:

```
-- Core.lua --

local function GUI_table()
  local GUI = {}

  -- Template for GUI elements
  GUI.Element = {}
  function GUI.Element:new(name)
    local elm = {}
    setmetatable(elm, self)
    self.__index = self
    return elm
  end

  ...add a bunch of GUI.do_this = function()....

  return GUI

  end
GUI = GUI_table()
```

All of the GUI elements are separate files of the same form:

```
-- Class - Button.lua --

if not GUI then throw_a_missing_library_error_and_quit end

GUI.Button = GUI.Element:new()
function GUI.Button:draw()
...etc...
```

I'm currently loading them from the parent script via `loadfile("Core.lua")()`. This works well enough, but it places *GUI* in the global table with the associated overhead for lookups. Trying to rewrite things so that *GUI* can be local has, thus far, not gone well. I've tried:

```
local GUI
loadfile("Core.lua")()
loadfile("Class - Button.lua")()
...
```

Fails because the main script's *GUI* calls all go to the local _GUI, but loaded files can't see or add to it because of scoping.

```
loadfile("Core.lua")()
loadfile("Class - Button.lua")()
local GUI = GUI
```

Runs fine, but doesn't make a difference performancewise: Errors in module code still trace back to the module (i.e. "line 23 in Class - Button.lua"), which leads me to assume the modules are still held within their own scope and my local *GUI* isn't actually being touched.

I've also tried having *Core.lua* return the *GUI* table directly, so the main script can have `local GUI = loadfile("Core.lua")()`, but I ran into trouble giving the element modules access to it, as above. I know, scoping.

So, given all of the above, is there a "correct" way to write/structure the modules so that everything ends up in a local *GUI*? I get the impression that the defunct `module(..., package.seeall)` functionality would have solved this... maybe not though.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with circular dependencies. I notice that `Element` and `Button` go *inside* `GUI`, but they don't *depend* on `GUI` for their construction. Putting `Element` in its own file will allow you to make everything local.

```
-- Core.lua --

local GUI = {}

-- Template for GUI elements
GUI.Element = require 'Element'

GUI.Button = require 'Button'

return GUI

-- Element.lua --

return {
  new = function(self, name)
    local elm = {}
    setmetatable(elm, self)
    self.__index = self
    return elm
  end,
}

-- Class - Button.lua --

Button = require('Element'):new()
function Button:draw()
end

return Button
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and as far as the detail given in my post that makes perfect sense.

In the code I left out for brevity there actually are a lot of calls to _GUI.___ - _Core.lua_ handles user input, redrawing elements, and then provides utility functions that Lua and the API I'm working with don't. (I know, bad code smell. The scope issues I'm asking about also led to me keeping it all together).

All of the element classes use _Core_'s functions extensively - I'm happy to edit the OP, or provide more code here - not sure of what StackOverflow considers "good manners".

Thanks.

Comment: The UI stuff is probably high-level and needs (possibly indirect) access to everything else. Utility functions are probably low-level stuff that everything else depends on. You should be able to make significant progress by extracting the utility functions to their own file. If that doesn't finish the job, keep looking for things you can move to their own files until there are no more circular dependencies. As for editing your question, it sounds like your actual code is just a more tangled version of what you already posted. I don't know if it would change my answer that much.